# VBA Excel Loop Assistance

Tags: vba, excel

Any assistance into turning this into a for loop would be appreciated.  I have listed Columns G and H but need it to go to AA.

Regards

Sun

```
Sub AutoSum()  
Dim Area As Range, MyColumn As String    
MyColumn = "G"    
    For Each Area In Columns(MyColumn).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas    
        SumAddr = Area.Address(False, False)    
        Area.Offset(Area.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & SumAddr & ")"    
    Next Area    
MyColumn = "H"    
    For Each Area In Columns(MyColumn).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas    
        SumAddr = Area.Address(False, False)    
        Area.Offset(Area.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & SumAddr & ")"    
    Next Area    
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me clear some things, you want to sum specified cells in G and H and out put in AA?

Answer (score 0):

> For c = 7 to 8 'G to H
>
> ```
>  For Each Area In Columns(c).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
>      SumAddr = Area.Address(False, False)
>      Area.Offset(Area.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & SumAddr & ")"
>  Next Area
> ```
>
> Next c

Comment: Maybe it would be nice to expand this answer and explain how and why you did it this way. So the OP can self-help in the future

Comment: I used the code from the question. All I added was a for-next loop and used column indexes. Reason being that you can use one loop instead of many statements as requested in the question. Not sure how to expand the answer beyond that.